# How to change default options of Visual Studio build using CMake

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, cmake

Using Cmake, we use the following command

`cmake CMakeLists.txt -G "Visual Studio 11"`

to generate a Visual Studio 2012 solution file, which by-default uses `/fp:precise` as floating point option. Is there any way to change this to `/fp:fast` in CMake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify options with [various CMake variables](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#section_VariablesforLanguages), e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` for C++ compiler options. Try `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /fp:fast")`. I think you can also change them from within the GUI (tick the Advanced checkmark). For C you'd have to use the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS...` variants.